# OpenGL Color half of a cube

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glut

I am trying to color half of a cube to look like its filled with water. In the code below I draw the cube with the white edges:

```
void initGL() {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); 
    glClearDepth(1.0f); 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); 
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); 
}

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    glLoadIdentity(); 

    glTranslatef(-3.0f, 0.0f, -9.0f); 

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    glEnd(); 
    glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

but I don't know how to color half of it without erasing the white edges. And besides that I had to animate it so water could go up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that things like `glBegin`, `glEnd` are deprecated (even `glVertexPointer` and `glEnableClientState`).
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification).

---

But based on your code, I recommend to define an array of vertex data ([`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml)) 
and to client-side capability ([`glEnableClientState`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml)), to solve your issue.
Further define arrays of indices and use [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) to
render (indexed) primitives from array data.

Define the vertex coordinates:

```
GLfloat water_height = -0.5f;
GLfloat vertices[] =
{
    -1.0f, -1.0f,         -1.0f,  // 0
     1.0f, -1.0f,         -1.0f,  // 1
     1.0f, -1.0f,          1.0f,  // 2
    -1.0f, -1.0f,          1.0f,  // 3

    -1.0f,  1.0f,         -1.0f,  // 5
     1.0f,  1.0f,         -1.0f,  // 6
     1.0f,  1.0f,          1.0f,  // 7
    -1.0f,  1.0f,          1.0f,  // 8

    -1.0f,  water_height, -1.0f,  // 9
     1.0f,  water_height, -1.0f,  // 10
     1.0f,  water_height,  1.0f,  // 11
    -1.0f,  water_height,  1.0f   // 12
};
```

Define the indices for the "water" quads:

```
// 6 quad indices for the 6 sides of the water cube
GLuint water_indices[] = 
{ 
    0, 1, 2, 3,
    0, 1, 9, 8,
    1, 2, 10, 9,
    2, 3, 11, 10,
    3, 0, 8, 11,
    8, 9, 10, 11
};
```

Define the indices for the edges:

```
// 8 edges for the part of the cube which is not filled with water 
GLuint edge_indices[] = 
{ 
    4, 5, 
    5, 6,
    6, 7,
    7, 4,
    4, 8,
    5, 9,
    6, 10,
    7, 11
};
```

Draw the quads and the lines:

```
glVertexPointer( 3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices );
glEnableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );

glColor4f( 0.3f, 0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glDrawElements( GL_QUADS, 6 * 4, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, water_indices );

glColor4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
glDrawElements( GL_LINES, 8 * 2, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, edge_indices );

glDisableClientState( GL_VERTEX_ARRAY );
```

Preview:

[image: water]